# Copy Paste Cells through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a code which copies the Sheet1 Cells A2 and B2 then paste that cells into Sheet2 Cells G5 and G6.

I have been trying to create a loop that after first scenario when i run the code again it should copy the Cells `A3 and B3` then paste into `Cells G5 and G6 (these cell will always be same)`.

I want to step forward by one row every time i run the macro.

I have tried with OFFSET function but it works just once.

```
Sub copy()
Dim lRow, i As Long
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheet1
Set sht2 = Sheet2

sht1.Cells(2, 1).Offset(1, i).Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(5, 7)
sht1.Cells(2, 2).Offset(1, i).Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(6, 7)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I'm pleased you have a solution here. I just wanted to show you my copy-paste tool 'Pattern Transfer' - it's designed for this purpose (transferring data from one structure to another), and it is completely configurable. It's a macro-based Excel file, free to download here: https://patterntransfer.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time you run, locate the previous value in the input table and copy the next value

```
option explicit

Sub copy()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheet1
Set sht2 = Sheet2



dim r as range
set r = range(sht1.Cells(2, 1), sht1.Cells(2, 1).end(xlDown))

dim offset_row as variant

if isempty(sht2.Cells(5, 7).value) then
  offset_row=0
else
  offset_row=application.worksheetfunction.match(sht2.Cells(5, 7).value, r, 0)
endif

if not iserror(offset_row) then
  if offset_row <> r.rows.count then
    sht1.Cells(2, 1).offset(offset_row, 0).Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(5, 7)
    sht1.Cells(2, 1).offset(offset_row, 1).Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(6, 7)
  endif
endif



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but its takes me directly to the end of the values @JohnnieL whereas it should go one by one over running the code.

Comment: so you want to step forward by one row every time you run the macro?

Comment: try that now ^^

Comment: Thank you very much its working now but there is one more problem that is when it goes to the last row i.e row8 for now it should stop on that row instead of empty output in G5 and G6 and run again from row2 like Exit Sub

Comment: ok so we need to test for `offset_row = r.rows.count` which is the "we are at the end" condition - why dont you attempt that yourself?

Comment: I did it but an error is appear that is Object Required after changed it Set r = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: see modification